# HTTP request success handled as an error (firefox)?

Tags: angular, http, firefox

There is a POST rest on my app that gets data from another service. It takes somewhere between 10 to 100 seconds to return response. On firefox, when it takes more time (usually around 30 seconds or more) the response is returned with status code 200 and proper body (as it looks in devtools), but Angular app handles it as an error. The problem doesn't occur on other browsers.

```js
this._http.post(url, {}).subscribe({
            next: (response) => {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: (error) => {
                console.log("Error");
            },
        });
```

In the example above, the "Error" is logged in console despite the success status in devtools. (_http is a HttpClient from @angular/common)

There is also an error in the console: `A ServiceWorker intercepted the request and encountered an unexpected error. ngsw-worker.js`

What could be the reason?

Comment: Try debugging ngsw-worker.js. Apparently, the intercepting code there is failing

Answer (score 0):

Possibly due to extensions on your Firefox browser. Try removing/disabling the extensions, if you have installed any, on your Firefox browser.

Also, check if your version of Firefox supports service workers

Comment: I'm up do to date with firefox updates. The extensions also aren't the problem. It works in incognito, but it also works with standard browsing and history disabled, so it is definetely sw problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Apps (in production mode), or as PWA typically make use of Service Workers. For Angular Apps this is the ngsw-worker.js file. You could have multiple service workers, but typically one one (per scope) is used, and usually only one per project, unless you have Cloud Messaging, in which case different service workers could be responsible for different functionalities. In your case, it is probably the serving and loading of resources.

You could test this locally in a development environment, where service workers are not used (though they could), or you can bypass service workers by unregistering them in your main.ts file.

```
// service worker
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
    registrations.forEach(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  });
}
```

You can also test it in your devtools by unregistering the service worker manually and see if the issue persists.

Alternatively, in your Angular application, when making the HTTP request, include the **ngsw-bypass** header for the specific requests that you want to bypass the service worker. This will likely work.

Comment: I didn't know about the ngsw-bypass header. Let me check it out and I'll come back with the answer!